# Proof that $\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi/2 }{f(\sin2x)\sin x dx } $=$\sqrt2\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi/4}{f(\cos2x)\cos x dx }$

Tags: definite-integrals

> How would you prove $\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi/2 }{f(\sin2x)\sin x dx  }
>  $=$\sqrt2\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi/4}{f(\cos2x)\cos x dx  }$ ?

Its a problem from IIT-JEE 1990. I've tried it but i'm just going round and round. Give your suggestions please.

Comment: By the change of variable $x=\pi/4-u$ and the fact that $\sqrt2\cos x=\cos u+\sin u$, the RHS is $$\int_0^{\pi/4}f(\sin 2u)(\cos u+\sin u)du$$ hence it suffices to show that $$\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}f(\sin 2x)\sin xdx=\int_0^{\pi/4}f(\sin 2u)\cos udu.$$ Now, use the change of variable $x=\pi/2-v$ in the LHS, with $\sin 2x=\sin 2v$ and $\sin x=\cos v$, to conclude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}f(\sin2x)\sin x\, dx &= \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(\cos 2y)\sin(y+\pi/4) dy \qquad \mbox{ (by } x=y+\pi/4)\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(\cos 2y)(\sin y + \cos  y) dy\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} f(\cos 2y) \cos  y\,  dy \qquad ( f(\cos 2y) \sin y \mbox { is an odd function})\\
&=\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4} f(\cos 2y) \cos  y\,  dy  \qquad ( f(\cos 2y) \cos y \mbox { is an even function})
\end{align*}

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval is zero.